# Closing ConfirmDialog from method

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I have some class with 2 methods. First method is invoking confirm dialog and second is thread listener waiting for complete status. If the listener is executed, I want close the confirm dialog. Is it possible?

My code:

```
public class NewNetworkGame implements ThreadListener {

ReadMsg read;
Network net;
// my dialog
JOptionPane cancelDialog;

boolean accepted = false;
boolean readStopped = false;

public NewNetworkGame(Network net) {
    this.net = net;
    read = new ReadMsg(this.net);
    ThreadHandler rm = read;
    rm.addListener(this);
    rm.start();

    JPanel cancelConn = new JPanel();
    cancelConn.add(new JLabel("Waiting for host response..."));

    // showing dialog
    int result = cancelDialog.showConfirmDialog(null, cancelConn, "Host response", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION); 
    // client clicked on cancel option while thread is still reading host response       
    if (result == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION && !accepted && !readStopped) {
        net.sendReject();   
    }

    if (!readStopped) {
        read.interrupt();
    }

}

@Override
public void notifyOfThreadComplete(Thread thread) {

    readStopped = true;

    if (net.getAcceptMsg().equals(read.getStr())) {
        accepted = true;
    }

    // closing dialog
    cancelDialog.setValue(JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
    // generates: java.lang.NullPointerException
}

}
```

I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` from `cancelDialog.setValue(JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)` in listener handler. Can you anybody help how to close confirm dialog right?

**Update with solution.**
Working code:

```
public class NewNetworkGame implements ThreadListener {

ReadMsg read;
Network net;

boolean accepted = false;
boolean readStopped = false;

final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();


public NewNetworkGame(Network net) {
    this.net = net;
    read = new ReadMsg(this.net);
    ThreadHandler rm = read;
    rm.addListener(this);
    rm.start();


    JPanel cancelConn = new JPanel();
    cancelConn.add(new JLabel("Waiting for host response..."));
    Object[] options = {"Abort"};

    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(dialog, cancelConn, "Host response", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);        

    System.out.println("clicked");

    if (!accepted && !readStopped) {
        System.out.println("aborted");
        net.sendReject();   
    }

    if (!readStopped) {
        read.interrupt();
    }

}

@Override
public void notifyOfThreadComplete(Thread thread) {

    readStopped = true;

    if (net.getAcceptMsg().equals(read.getStr())) {
        accepted = true;
    }

    dialog.setVisible(false);

}

}
```

Comment: You can check it with result right?when you Invoke this code  cancelDialog.setValue(JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION); at that Time there is not an instance of Joptionpane. taht why null point expception.

Comment: Can you write some more about checking it with result?

Comment: I donno waht you are trying to acheive with the Code, see When trying to Call cancelDialog.setValue, Instance of cacelDialog is NULL, Because JoptionPane will automatically close the DialogBox after You Click on Ok/Cancel. so why you need to try with SetCancel(), Problem is ShowDialog, Application can't Click on any other Forms Entities. After Closes the dilog CancelDialog istance is null.

Comment: The dialog is giving option for user to close waiting for another user. But if the other user make some action, I need close waiting dialog automatic.

Comment: *"**Update with solution.** Working code:"*  You should enter that as an answer then (when the site allows) accept the answer.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this  sample line of code

```
    @Override
    public void notifyOfThreadComplete(Thread thread) {

        readStopped = true;

        if (net.getAcceptMsg().equals(read.getStr())) {
            accepted = true;
        }

        // closing dialog
         if(cancelDialog != null)
             {
        cancelDialog.setValue(JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
         }

}
```

Comment: This will not close blocking dialog.

Comment: Now you are getting an exception.?